# Kotlin function overloading (varargs vs single parameter)

Tags: kotlin, variadic-functions, overloading

I have two functions check if String/Strings are blank.

```
fun isBlank(s: String?) : Boolean {
            return s.isNullOrBlank()
        }

fun isBlank(vararg strings: String) : Boolean {
            return strings.isEmpty() ||
                    strings.any { isBlank(it) }
        }
```

So I try to call first function from the second one but seems it tries to call itself. For instance it works nice in java:

```
public static boolean isBlank(final String string) {
        return string == null || string.trim().isEmpty();
}

public static boolean isBlank(final String... strings) {
        return strings.length == 0
                || Arrays.stream(strings).anyMatch(StringUtil::isBlank);
}
```

How to handle such a situation in kotlin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the same thing as in Java with a [function reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references), which would look like this:

```
fun isBlank(vararg strings: String) : Boolean {
    return strings.isEmpty() || strings.any(::isBlank)
}
```

This works because [`any`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/any.html) expects a parameter of type `(T) -> Boolean`, `T` in this case being `String`. Only the non-`vararg` function has this type, the `vararg` function's type is actually `(Array<out String>) -> Boolean`.

Comment: Why does that call the "correct" overload to be called?

Comment: I've added explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's a little problem, I guess: The `vararg` function can not be called with `null` currently, you only accept `String`. Checking for `null` doesn't make sense anyway. You would have to change the parameter `strings` to type `vararg strings: String?`. Another solution is casting to `String?` inside `any`:

```
fun isBlank(vararg strings: String): Boolean {
    return strings.isEmpty() ||
            strings.any { isBlank(it as String?) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second function calls itself because the type of **`it`** (in `strings.any { isBlank(it) }`) is `String`, which is the type this second function accepts. The compiler chooses this function because, though the first one also accepts `String`, it receives `String?`.

Anyway, you could have just this function:

```
fun isBlank(vararg strings: String?)
        = strings.any { it == null || it.isEmpty() || it.isBlank() }
```