# Kotlin invokes wrong overloaded java method with variable number of arguments

Tags: java, kotlin

I have two method in java:

```
Object get(A a)
Object get(A a, B... b)
```

and when I'm trying to invoke first method in Kotlin

```
get(someInstance)
```

It always invokes second method with empty second parameter.

How could I call first method from Kotlin in this case?

Comment: it should be working without any problem!

Comment: The first function is a subset of second, when size of list b is zero. So second will always get called. You should call first inside of second for this special case (b.length == 0).

Comment: This methods have a fully different implementation, so it doesn't suit me

Comment: Addition to the question: [proof](https://ideone.com/YDLdM1) that this works fine in Java.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it.. :(

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this doesn't happen when methods are defined in Kotlin:

```
class A
class B

fun f(a: A) { println("one") }
fun f(a: A, vararg rest: B) { println("many") }

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    f(A())
}
```

prints `one`. Searching on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=kotlin%20vararg%20java I can't find this exact issue (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11150 is close, but it has `get(Object a)` as the non-vararg overload). So I suggest you post it there if you can reproduce it.

Two possible workarounds:

1. trying to adapt a trick from [Kotlin function overloading (varargs vs single parameter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49486877/kotlin-function-overloading-varargs-vs-single-parameter):

   ```
   val a: A = ...
   a.let(::get)
   ```
2. define a wrapper in Java:

   ```
   Object getNonVararg(A a) { return get(a); }
   ```

and call it from Kotlin.